# Can I have an alert box displayed over a lightbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, lightbox, alert

I wish to display an alert box  with 'Ok', 'Cancel' buttons, when I click a button in my lightbox. Is this scenario possible? And if yes, can I customize the alert box? Please someone suggest the possible solution. If there are example demos, please provide me the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a jQuery dialog instead of an alert box. See example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to have a lightbox over a lightbox?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple lighboxes. They simply float over your site. With jQuery UI dialog, you can drag and resize them. You can also disabled those options.

Answer (score 3):

Lightboxes are simple layers over the other site elements, but alert boxes are browser level alerts which show over all the content. So yeah, you can have javascript alert boxes over lightboxes. If you want just one Okay button, you can use the `alert()` function. If you want to show two buttons, you can use the `confirm()` button. You can also take user input (text) using the `prompt()` function. For examples, you can look here: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to have a lightbox over a lightbox? Is it good to do so?

Comment: Yes (and no). The lightbox sits on top of everything because of its `z-index` value. The element with the highest `z-index` value sits on top (provided it has a `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. However, I would not put a lightbox over another, and many implementations of lightbox can't have multiple instances.

Comment: Using confirm would be more robust - but you can't style it. If you need the styling then maybe have a look at Hussein's suggestion.

Comment: You can set z-index value if working with jQuery UI dialog. It's in the documentation. You can also set width, height, add buttons, call functions when button is clicked, animate it, destroy it and allot more.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the defaul alert() by the code

```
 (function() {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function(args) {
      doAlert(args); //your own function
  };
})();
```

Then you can use a jquery dialog as you like. But keep in mind the jquery dialog is non-block as the original alertbox does.